# Creating a matrix from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, parsing, numpy, matrix

I've been working on Python for around 2 months now so I have a OK understanding of it.

My goal is to create a matrix using CSV data, then populating that matrix from the data in the 3rd column of that CSV file.

I came up with this code thus far:

```
import csv

import csv
def readcsv(csvfile_name):
      with open(csvfile_name) as csvfile:
      file=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

#remove rubbish data in first few rows

      skiprows = int(input('Number of rows to skip? '))
           for i in range(skiprows):
                _ = next(file)

#change strings into integers/floats

            for z in file:
                 z[:2]=map(int, z[:2])
                 z[2:]=map(float, z[2:])
                 print(z[:2])
        return
```

After removing the rubbish data with the above code, the data in the CSV file looks like this:

```
   Input:
   1  1  51 9 3 
   1  2  39 4 4
   1  3  40 3 9
   1  4  60 2 . 
   1  5  80 2 .
   2  1  40 6 .
   2  2  28 4 .
   2  3  40 2 .
   2  4  39 3 . 
   3  1  10 . .
   3  2  20 . .
   3  3  30 . .
   3  4  40 . .
   .  .   . . .
```

The output should look like this:

```
      1   2   3   4  .  .
   1  51  39  40  60
   2  40  28  40  39
   3  10  20  30  40
   .
   .
```

There are about a few thousand rows and columns in this CSV file, however I'm only interested is the first 3 columns of the CSV file. So the first and second columns are basically like co-ordinates for the matrix, and then populating the matrix with data in the 3rd column.

After lots of trial and error, I realised that numpy was the way to go with matrices. This is what I tried thus far with example data:

```
  left_column =   [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
  middle_column = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4]
  right_column =  [1., 5., 3., 7., 2., 6., 4., 8.]

  import numpy as np
  m = np.zeros((max(left_column), max(middle_column)), dtype=np.float)
  for x, y, z in zip(left_column, middle_column, right_column):
      x -= 1 # Because the indicies are 1-based
      y -= 1 # Need to be 0-based
      m[x, y] = z
  print(m)

  #: array([[ 1., 2., 3., 4.],
  #:        [ 5., 6., 7., 8.]])
```

However, it is unrealistic for me to specify all of my data in my script to generate the matrix. I tried using the generators to pull the data out of my CSV file but it didn't work well for me.

I learnt as much numpy as I could, however it appears like it requires my data to already be in matrix form, which it isn't.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the last  two columns. The first three are clear... (row, column, value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution using only the csv library, and working with the index\position in the csv (using an offset which I use to mantain memory on the current row)

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    list_of_list = []
    j=0
    lines = [line for line in spamreader]
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        list_ = []
        if(len(lines)<=i+j):
            break;
        first = lines[i+j][0]
        while(first == lines[i+j][0]):
            list_.append(lines[i+j][2])
            j+=1
            if(len(lines)<=i+j):
                break;
        j-=1
        list_of_list.append(list(map(float,list_)))

maxlen = len(max(list_of_list))
print("\t"+"\t".join([str(el) for el in range(1,maxlen+1)])+"\n")
for i in range(len(list_of_list)):
    print(str(i+1)+"\t"+"\t".join([str(el) for el in list_of_list[i]])+"\n")
```

Anyway the solution posted by Saullo is more elegant

This is my output:

```
        1       2       3       4       5

1       51.0    39.0    40.0    60.0    80.0

2       40.0    28.0    40.0    39.0

3       10.0    20.0    30.0    40.0
```

I wrote a new version of the code with an iterator, because the csv is too big to fit in memory

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    list_of_list = []

    line1 = next(spamreader)
    first = line1[0]
    list_ = [line1[2]]
    for line in spamreader:
        while(line[0] == first):
            list_.append(line[2])
            try:
                line = next(spamreader)
            except :
                break;
        list_of_list.append(list(map(float,list_)))
        list_ = [line[2]]
        first = line[0]

maxlen = len(max(list_of_list))
print("\t"+"\t".join([str(el) for el in range(1,maxlen+1)])+"\n")
for i in range(len(list_of_list)):
    print(str(i+1)+"\t"+"\t".join([str(el) for el in list_of_list[i]])+"\n")
```

Anyway probably you need to work on the Matrix in chunks (and doing swaps) because probably the data wan't fit in a 2d array

Comment: Hey, I tried running the code and there was a error on line 7 with "MemoryError". Any thoughts?

Comment: You used as input the csv which you posted before, or another csv? a bigger one, maybe? I haven't tested it on bigger example

Comment: probably your csv is too big to fit in memory, so you need to use an iterator

Comment: Yeah, the CSV file is around 800mbs, so it's pretty large. I tried using generators/iterators in the past, but was unsuccessful in doing so. Also resorted to just use list comprehension but was also unable to conver it :( So i thought numpy was the way to go. I could send the CSV file if needed

Comment: I don't need it, later I'll try to write something with an iterator

Comment: Thank you so much! Much appreciated

Comment: try the new version, let me know how do you do

Comment: Hey, I got an index error saying: IndexError: list index out of range for the while(line[0] == first) line. After I skip the rows with my original code, the data is like this: [1, 1, 3.2, 4.3 ..]
                         [1, 1, 5.3, 2.1 ..] The lists are spaced by a return, not in this comment format. So in each row, there's pretty much only 1 list.

Comment: nevermind, it works with the example data. I tried to use my previous code to skip some rows but it didnt seem to work, got a lot of rubbish data in the first few.

Comment: Also, could you please explain what each line of code means? I don't really understand line 9 onwards. I see you using index numbers, but other than that not too sure

Comment: do you mean: list_ = [line[2]]? It's the list with first element of the first row. Anyway in my example I've used a csv similar to yours, but with "," (comma) as delimeter

Comment: "first" represent the number in the first column, while passing all the lines it's the same, means that we are in the same row, and so I append the current value to the current list\row

Comment: So basically: for each element in the CSV file, while the first number of the first column is the same as the first one, it'll append the value in list_? Sorry I'm a bit bconfused

Comment: yes exactly, but when the value in the first column isn't the same anymore starts a new list (which is a new row in the matrix)

Comment: in your example, the iterator go until the 5th row and fill the first row of our matrix, (because the first 5 row have "1") then there will be a new "first" which is "2" and then a new row of our matrix, until there are "2" on the first column

Comment: when the first element of the first column will change, there will be a new "list_" which represent a new row for our final matrix

Comment: basically: while (my_current_number = first) append to the list_, if my_current_number isn't anymore = first, create a new list_ with the next elements (changing first with the next different element in the first column)

Answer (score 4):

You should seriously consider using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It is really ideal for this sort of work. I can't give you an actual solution because I don't have your data, but I would try something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=[0,1,2], names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns='B', values='C')
```

The second line imports the data into a pandas DataFrame object (change the names into something more useful for your application). The pivot table creates the matrix you are looking for, and gracefully handles any missing data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Would it be helpful if I sent the CSV file? I couldn't get it to work after numerous tries. The error is: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_csv'

Comment: @dizzyLife: Which version of Pandas are you using? If you have imported pandas as pd, type "pd.__version__" into python. I am using pandas 0.18.0, so maybe you need a newer pandas version?

Comment: @dizzyLife: Ignore earlier comment, read_csv has been in pandas since the beginning. Your error probably means pandas is not installed correctly. Did running "import pandas as pd" generate any exceptions?

Comment: Is there a way where I'd be able to use that code, and then skip a few rows? A lot of rubbish data I don't want.

Comment: If you mean at the beginning of the file, you can use the skiprows option in read_csv. Otherwise, pivot_table returns a Pandas DataFrame, which has many options for slicing and selecting data. See here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: Just tried it, it worked! However, when I tried it with a much larger csv data set, there was a MemoryError. Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` to load this data very conveniently.

Working with your input:

```
 Input:
   1  1  51 9 3 
   1  2  39 4 4
   1  3  40 3 9
   1  4  60 2 . 
   1  5  80 2 .
   2  1  40 6 .
   2  2  28 4 .
   2  3  40 2 .
   2  4  39 3 . 
   3  1  10 . .
   3  2  20 . .
   3  3  30 . .
   3  4  40 . .
   .  .   . . .
```

You could do:

```
l, c, v = np.loadtxt('test.txt', skiprows=1).T
m = coo_matrix((v, (l-1, c-1)), shape=(l.max(), c.max()))
```

Then you can convert the `coo_matrix` to a `np.ndarray`:

```
In [9]: m.toarray()
Out[9]:
array([[ 51.,  39.,  40.,  60.,  80.],
       [ 40.,  28.,  40.,  39.,   0.],
       [ 10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,   0.]])
```

Comment: Hey, firstly thanks for the help. I tried to run the code by replacing test.txt with a csv file called file.csv, but I got the error: IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or personal software is blocking the connection. Does this meman I just have to put all the data in a notepad?

Comment: @dizzyLife sure, but be sure you have kept only the valid data, in this case I kept only up to the third column, otherwise you would have to do: `l, c, v = np.loadtxt("file.csv", skiprows=1).T[:3, :]` to limit reading up to the third colum (when transposed up to the third row)

Comment: @dizzyLife also, check if your delimiter in the `csv` file is something different from blank spaces. If yes, you have to pass `delimiter=","` to the `loadtxt` function (or another delimiter character that you have there)

Comment: The file is too big for me to copy paste data into a seperate file, hence the use of a csv. Is there any way I could contact you?

Comment: @dizzyLife no need to copy all the data, just load using `l, c, v = np.loadtxt("file.csv", skiprows=1).T[:3, :]`, or pass `delimiter` if necessary

Comment: I finally got it! However, the only thing I'm fussed about is the 0's. The values are coming up incorrectly as you go through the array. For example, even when there are no 0's in my csv file, my output is [[ 51.  39.  40.  60.  70.  40.  30.  20.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  10.   5.   2.  40.  20.  10.]]

Comment: Nevermind, just figured it out. Also, what would happen to the code if i wanted to my output to be like the one above (in the post) where I include the first column as the column and the second column as the first row on top? One last question, it worked with the example data but didn't with the actual CSV because there's a ValueError: could not convert string to float. All of the data in the 3rd column are actually floats.